# forcing https with primary domain & www. but NOT subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a domain and SSL certificate installed. it's NOT a wildcard SSL.

We have a third-party url rewrite for one of the subdomains that is hosted on their services - something I can't get rid of or control.

They do not have an SSL on the subdomain. Now that I've installed the SSL, the subdomain is always redirecting to https as well, which is throwing an error.

I want the sub to go to the http and the primary domain only to go to https.

I originally had the following in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I've since removed this and everything is still directing to https.

Comment: new browser, cleared cache, different browser (chrome & ffox) and also ran it through my phone (different isp) and tried it through browserstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a third-party url rewrite for one of the subdomains that is
>   hosted on their services

Is this something that is being done outside of your .htaccess file? This 3rd party rewrite might be causing the issue.

However if you just want to ignore the subdomain just add it to the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the subdomain is pointed to from the DNS records, so there's nothing in the htaccess file about it. Just ignoring the subdomain seems to have worked (yay!) however I'm having some issues with Chrome that I think is a browser problem. Chrome seems to be trying to force https on subdomains once its found the primary domain with an ssl. part of it being very picky i guess... Thanks!